# Act As Taggable Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tags showing in my category show view. When someone views the Mobile Phones Category they will see tags at the top such as iphone, apple, 16gb, black and ect. When someone clicks on 16gb, it should show every item with 16gb tagged in it.

I've worked on this error for 12 hours and can't fix it.

When someone clicks on a tag i get this error.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CategoriesController#show
Couldn't find Category with 'id'=

    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end
```

I can't figure out how to fix it?

Im using act_as_taggable gem.

Here is category controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category,   only: [:show]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: [:destroy, :index, :edit]

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def show
    if params[:tag]
      @items = Item.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @items = Item.where(category_id: @category.id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update(category_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @category.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to categories_url, notice: 'Category was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name, :parent_id)
    end

    # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.try(:admin?)
    end

end
```

Here is my category show view.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class = "col-md-3">
    <h1>
      <strong><%= @category.name %></strong>
    </h1>
</div>

<div class = "col-md-9">
    <div id="tag_cloud">
      <% tag_cloud Item.tag_counts, %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
        <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class = "col-md-12">
    <div class="line-separator"></div>
</div>

<div class = "col-md-12">
    <div id="items" class="transitions-enabled">
        <% @items.each do |item| %>
            <div class="box panel panel-default">
              <div class="itemlisttitle"><%= item.title %></div>    
            <%= link_to image_tag(item.image.url (:medium)), item %>
              <div class ="panel-body">
              <div class = "itemlistprice">$<%= item.price %></div>
              <div class = "itemlistretailer"><%= image_tag item.user.avatar(:thumb) %> Retailer: <%= link_to item.user.username, item.user %></div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is routes. So you can see how the tags are routed.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


      resources :categories

      get 'password_resets/new'

      get 'password_resets/edit'

      get 'sessions/new'

      resources :users
      get 'user_items'  => 'users#show_user_items'
      root 'items#home'
      get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
      get 'show'  => 'users#show'
      get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
      post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
      delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
      resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
      resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

      resources :items
      get 'items_new' => 'items#new'

      get 'tags/:tags', to: 'categories#show', as: :tag
```

Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150731101116) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "ancestry"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "categories", ["ancestry"], name: "index_categories_on_ancestry"

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  add_index "items", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_items_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  add_index "items", ["user_id"], name: "index_items_on_user_id"

  create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "taggable_id"
    t.string   "taggable_type"
    t.integer  "tagger_id"
    t.string   "tagger_type"
    t.string   "context",       limit: 128
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context", "tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "taggings_idx", unique: true
  add_index "taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "taggings_count", default: 0
  end

  add_index "tags", ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name", unique: true

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.boolean  "admin",               default: false
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated",           default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string   "reset_digest"
    t.string   ">"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
    t.text     "description"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you are sending only params[:tag] butto find category you have to send id as well, try following

Change

```
<%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
```

To

```
<%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name, id: @category.id), class: css_class %>
```

and check again

Comment: You need use `tag_path(tag: tag.name, id: tag.id)` because that's the id of the tag being clicked on. `@category.id` is the id of the one currently being viewed, which is not what you want to send in the link.

Comment: But even then, this might not work because you are sending two params when the route is only expecting one.

Answer (score 0):

When a user clicks on a tag `tag.name` is put as a parameter and the route goes to the `show` action of the `categories` controller, naming the parameter `tags`. The `show` action has a `before_action` method set which tries to find the relevant `Category` object based on the `id` which it gets from the parameter called `id`.

There's no parameter called `id` when the `set_category` method runs after the user clicks on a tag.

Change the method to this

```
def set_category
  if params[:tag]
    @category = Category.find_by_name(params[:tag])
  end
  if params[:id]
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

With this code the show action will work if you send the name of the tag as a parameter called `:tag` or the id as a parameter called `:id`